# While creating prolect getting error

Tags: android

I have created the new project in the eclipse and I am getting one error. It is not taking main method.Giving error as main can not be resolved or is not a type.I have build the project

Comment: What kind of project did you create?

Comment: public class First extends  Activity {

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}

Comment: And you're debugging as an android project and not an java project?

Comment: Do you have a xml file named `main.xml` in the `res/layout` folder of your android project? If not, create it.

Comment: I have created the folder and also main.xml file

Comment: And do you still get the error or ...?